# How to create a dynamic website without IIS

Tags: web

I want to create a dynamic website that does not support IIS. The area where I work does not allow anything to be installed in the server. The have a windows based server and I would like to create a dynamic website. IIS not allowed and server side languages like asp.net, php are not allowed. They did not say anything about client side. Is it possible to do?

Comment: You want to serve web content without a web server?

Comment: If it is your client or boss who decided this I suggest breaking up with them. The set up for website is completely inadequate.

Comment: What _is_ installed already on the server? What _are_ you allowed to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, a general answer to your question **Is it possible?** would be **No, it's not. And if you still find a way, it's not going to be worth the effort.**

For one thing, even without programming languages like ASP.NET or PHP, you still need a web server such as IIS to serve static content. There are of course alternatives to IIS specifically, but no web server at all means no serving web sites at all.

If you would be given an opportunity to server static content, you could possibly produce a web site that is dynamic at least on a per visit basis using client side scripting and cookies, but the things you could make that site do would be very limited, and without anything other than serving static content there is no saving things between sessions, or in any way affecting the server side of the application.

You have to ask yourself *why* you need to serve this website. Is this something your company would benefit from? If so, could you convince the IT department to setup an environment to serve it? Are there any other alternatives? And, perhaps the most important one: there are lots of free or almost free web hosting solutions out there. Why not just use one of them?

Answer (score 1):

There are many excellent reasons why you would want to create a dynamic website without using a web server.  Here are a couple:

- You are creating a website as a means of presenting a dataset with hyperlinks that you want to be able to archive on read-only media and ignore for 10 years or more (as you can do with books), and still be able to read  (IIS is very poor at backwards compatibility).
- You need to present your data to people who have no access to servers or the internet and have no idea how to turn their PC into a web server (there are many millions of such people in the developing world)

Yes, it's challenging, but if you want something to be readable by anyone, anywhere, anytime, and all you can count on are web browsers, there's no option.

Answer (score 0):

By saying you want to do it without IIS, I'm assuming you're implying Apache as well (since you reference no server-side languages).

It depends what you mean by 'dynamic'.  Essentially you'll be limited to

1. JavasScript, which means that you can manipulate information and elements already on the page.
2. iFrames - this would let you load external pages into elements and pages on the page.  These could be dynamic, and if they were on the same server you could manipulate it as well.  If it was from an external server, then you wouldn't have control over it from that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to set up an HTTP proxy, you can use JavaScript together with a service like [CouchOne](http://www.couchone.com/). You will need the proxy, since browsers [restrict AJAX calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).